# jquery dialoguebox reposition it to original position after dragging

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

i want to re position j query dialogue box when we drag it and we close it and reopen it ,below is sample code for same.

```
dialogBox.dialog({
                create: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').on('keydown', function                                                                 (ev) {
                        if (ev.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
                            closeDialogFunction();
                        }
                    });

                },
                closeOnEscape: false,
                modal: true,
                title: Title,
                buttons: [
                             {
                                 text: 'Yes'
                                 click: OkFunction()
                             },
                             {
                                 text: 'Cancel',
                                 click: CaccelFunction()
                             }
                ]

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added below line after loading the dialog box on screen

_dialogBox.dialog("option", "position", { my: "center", at: "center", of: window });

this works fine if we close dialog box and re open it